# Neo4j CE failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@473c001d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I was trying on NEO4J CE 3.2.1. Worked fine for a couple of days. Unable to start it after downloading APOC jars. I see below error on starting.

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 
'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@473c001d' was 
successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause 
exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.getParams()Ljava/util/Map;".
```

Below is the log it generated on starting neo4j. I tried reinstalling as an update and by deleting the neo4j folder from Documents folder and resulted in same.

```
2017-06-07 13:57:25.649+0000 WARN [o.n.i.p.PageCache] The dbms.memory.pagecache.size setting has not been configured. It is recommended that this setting is always explicitly configured, to ensure the system has a balanced configuration. Until then, a computed heuristic value of 6440222720 bytes will be used instead. 
2017-06-07 13:57:25.722+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
2017-06-07 13:57:25.737+0000 INFO [o.n.k.AvailabilityGuard] Requirement makes database unavailable: Database available
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Neo4j Kernel properties:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.bolt.type=BOLT
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.directories.neo4j_home=C:\Users\KON1299\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.import=import
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.http.type=HTTP
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.directories.database=C:\Users\KON1299\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.logs.http.enabled=false
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.https.type=HTTP
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.edition=community
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Diagnostics providers:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] org.neo4j.kernel.info.DiagnosticsManager
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] SYSTEM_MEMORY
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JAVA_MEMORY
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] OPERATING_SYSTEM
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JAVA_VIRTUAL_MACHINE
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] CLASSPATH
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] LIBRARY_PATH
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] NETWORK
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] System memory information:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.738+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total Physical memory: 15.43 GB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free Physical memory: 12.19 GB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Committed virtual memory: 711.41 MB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total swap space: 30.85 GB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free swap space: 27.05 GB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JVM memory information:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free  memory: 265.88 MB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total memory: 410.50 MB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Max   memory: 3.43 GB
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Garbage Collector: PS Scavenge: [PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space]
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Garbage Collector: PS MarkSweep: [PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space, PS Old Gen]
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Code Cache (Non-heap memory): committed=10.94 MB, used=10.90 MB, max=240.00 MB, threshold=0.00 B
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Metaspace (Non-heap memory): committed=40.38 MB, used=38.85 MB, max=-1.00 B, threshold=0.00 B
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Compressed Class Space (Non-heap memory): committed=6.38 MB, used=6.02 MB, max=1.00 GB, threshold=0.00 B
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: PS Eden Space (Heap memory): committed=134.00 MB, used=85.12 MB, max=1.20 GB, threshold=?
2017-06-07 13:57:25.739+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: PS Survivor Space (Heap memory): committed=39.50 MB, used=0.00 B, max=39.50 MB, threshold=?
2017-06-07 13:57:25.740+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: PS Old Gen (Heap memory): committed=237.00 MB, used=59.50 MB, max=2.57 GB, threshold=0.00 B
2017-06-07 13:57:25.740+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Operating system information:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.740+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Operating System: Windows 7; version: 6.1; arch: amd64; cpus: 4
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Process id: 8168@OF060R90L0SXV5
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Byte order: LITTLE_ENDIAN
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Local timezone: America/New_York
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JVM information:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Version: 25.131-b11
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Arguments: [-Dexe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_program_files_neo4j_ce_3.2.1_bin_neo4j-ce.exe, -Dexe4j.isInstall4j=true, -Dexe4j.moduleName=C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-ce.exe, -Dexe4j.tempDir=, -Dexe4j.unextractedPosition=0, -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ActiveState\Perl64 v5.16.1\site\bin;C:\Program Files\ActiveState\Perl64 v5.16.1\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\gradle-3.5\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\KON1299\AppData\Roaming\npm;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin, -Dexe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0, -Dinstall4j.launcherId=24, -Dinstall4j.swt=false]
2017-06-07 13:57:25.741+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Java classpath:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20CE%203.2.1/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.7-all.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [classpath] C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-desktop-3.2.1.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20CE%203.2.1/bin/neo4j-desktop-3.2.1.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [classpath] C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\plugins\apoc-3.1.3.7-all.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20CE%203.2.1/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [classpath] C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\classes
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Library path:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.746+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.747+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Windows\System32
2017-06-07 13:57:25.747+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Windows
2017-06-07 13:57:25.747+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Windows\System32\wbem
2017-06-07 13:57:25.747+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
2017-06-07 13:57:25.748+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\ActiveState\Perl64 v5.16.1\site\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.748+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\ActiveState\Perl64 v5.16.1\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.748+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro
2017-06-07 13:57:25.749+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption
2017-06-07 13:57:25.749+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.749+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions
2017-06-07 13:57:25.749+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\gradle-3.5\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\nodejs
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Users\KON1299\AppData\Roaming\npm
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] System.properties:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.moduleName = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-ce.exe
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.semaphoreName = Local\c:_program_files_neo4j_ce_3.2.1_bin_neo4j-ce.exe
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.boot.library.path = c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.consoleCodepage = cp0
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] path.separator = ;
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.country = US
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.script = 
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] install4j.exeDir = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\
2017-06-07 13:57:25.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.dir = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.variant = 
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.tempDir = 
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.nio.ch.bugLevel = 
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.udc.source = desktop
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons = true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] install4j.launcherId = 24
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.isInstall4j = true
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] install4j.swt = false
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.home = C:\Users\KON1299
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.timezone = America/New_York
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.encoding = Cp1252
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.name = KON1299
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.java.command = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-ce.exe
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.arch.data.model = 64
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.launchName = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\bin\neo4j-ce.exe
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.language = en
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] exe4j.unextractedPosition = 0
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] install4j.appDir = C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.1\
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.separator = \
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.cpu.endian = little
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.desktop = windows
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
2017-06-07 13:57:25.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Network information:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Software Loopback Interface 1:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 127.0.0.1
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (SSTP):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (L2TP):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (PPTP):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IPv6):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IP):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface RAS Async Adapter:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:75fa:63ed:4bb1:57cc%eth3
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:0:ffff:ffff:fffe%net4
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 10.9.87.85
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:dc25:660:cf70:e2a8%wlan0
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network):
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:5163:a5aa:66f3:9480%eth4
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:ec5c:8cab:1712:4d96%eth5
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:a09:5755%net7
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.942+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IP)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000:
2017-06-07 13:57:25.943+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2017-06-07 13:57:25.955+0000 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt Server extension loaded.
2017-06-07 13:57:25.956+0000 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2017-06-07 13:57:25.969+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store C:\Users\KON1299\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
2017-06-07 13:57:25.976+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store C:\Users\KON1299\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
2017-06-07 13:57:25.976+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not configured. Selected format from the store: RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8]
2017-06-07 13:57:26.170+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] IndexingService.init: indexes not specifically mentioned above are ONLINE
2017-06-07 13:57:27.073+0000 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] No commits found after last check point (which is at LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=50892771})
2017-06-07 13:57:27.084+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] IndexingService.start: indexes not specifically mentioned above are ONLINE
2017-06-07 13:57:27.106+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database health set to OK
2017-06-07 13:57:27.224+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Starting check pointing...
2017-06-07 13:57:27.225+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Starting store flush...
2017-06-07 13:57:27.317+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Store flush completed
2017-06-07 13:57:27.318+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Starting appending check point entry into the tx log...
2017-06-07 13:57:27.319+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Appending check point entry into the tx log completed
2017-06-07 13:57:27.321+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [58]:  Check pointing completed
2017-06-07 13:57:27.321+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [0]:  Starting log pruning.
2017-06-07 13:57:27.322+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [0]:  Log pruning complete.
2017-06-07 13:57:27.417+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2017-06-07 13:57:27.417+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2017-06-07 13:57:27.418+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
```

Comment: Try upgrading your version of APOC to [3.2](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/tree/3.2)

Comment: @Tezra I tried it by upgrading APOC to 3.2.1, but the issue still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I backed up my 'default.graphdb' folder, uninstalled Neo4J from my machine, reinstalled and replaced the new 'default.graphdb' with old one. Its working now.

Comment: Is the reinstall using APOC 3.2.1 or 3.1.3.7 (for anyone else with this problem)

Comment: I reinstalled and added APOC 3.2.1 plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like you are not using the APOC version matching your neo4j version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved for my Neo4j by removing all plugins  in `..\Neo4j X.X.X\plugins`